# WiX RemoveFolderEx 'Missing Folder Property'

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to use RemoveFolderEx to remove the Roaming/MyApp folder after uninstall, howver, after using the 'msiexec /i /l*v' command and checking the installer logs, I come across this:

> MSI (s) (64:40) [10:30:45:254]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSI860E.tmp, Entrypoint: WixRemoveFoldersEx MSI
>   (s) (64:74) [10:30:45:254]: Generating random cookie. MSI (s) (64:74)
>   [10:30:45:256]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 52380 (0xCC9C).
>   MSI (s) (64:8C) [10:30:45:657]: Running as a service. MSI (s) (64:8C)
>   [10:30:45:704]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action
>   server. WixRemoveFoldersEx:  Error 0x80070057: Missing folder
>   property: APPLICATIONFOLDER for row:
>   wrf4C77709F2CC40D572056B8DB1B2D0A3E CustomAction WixRemoveFoldersEx
>   returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due
>   to continue marking Action ended 10:30:45: WixRemoveFoldersEx. Return
>   value 1.

I just cant seem to get it it to work.  I followed this guide to implement it: http://www.hass.de/content/wix-how-use-removefolderex-your-xml-scripts

Here is my Wix code:

```xml
<Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
    <RegistrySearch Key="Software\Wah\MyApp" Root="HKCU" Type="raw" 
                    Id="REGSEARCH" Name="Path" />
</Property>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
      <Directory Id="PrivateData" Name="MyApp">
         <Component Id="RemovePrivateData" Guid="*">
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Wah\MyApp" 
                           Name="Path" Type="string" 
                           Value="[AppDataFolder]" KeyPath="yes"/>
            <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" 
                                 Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER"/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="AppDataFolder" On="uninstall"/>
         </Component>
      </Directory>        
   </Directory>
</Directory>
```

After looking at Regedit, the value does get set to the correct path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've looked at practically every issue with RemoveFolderEx and it hasn't particularly helped.

**EDIT: I've fixed this issue by adding a 'Secure="yes"' attribute to my APPLICATIONFOLDER property, like so:**

```
<Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Secure="yes">
    <RegistrySearch Key="Software\Wah\MyApp" Root="HKCU" Type="raw" 
                    Id="REGSEARCH" Name="Path" />
</Property>
```

Comment: At the end of the log file will be a list of all the properties with associated values, is ApplicationFolder in there? Perhaps the registry search didn't find the key it is searching for.

Comment: Yes it's there:

Property(C): APPLICATIONFOLDER = C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\